# salt-stack formula: N services one config file how to?

Tags: salt-stack

I want to move states from infra salt into dedicated formula.
These states manage two related services, which use the same config file.
Each of the services may be present on a machine, as well as both can.
The config file has common variables, as well as it can have service-specific variables.

Currently the config file is rendered by jinja using roles, which are defined in grains earlier:

```
{% set roles = salt['grains.get']('roles', []) %}
myvar1=A

{% if 'service1' in roles -%}
myvar2=B
{%- endif -%}

{%- if 'service2' in roles -%}
myvar3=C
{%- endif -%}
```

Now I realized that when I move to formula - I don't want to require 'roles' in grains. But I still want users of formula to be able use states something like this in any combination (i.e. either service1 or service2 or both) and somehow generate config file accordingly:

```
include:
  myservice/service1
  myservice/service2
```

Looking at existing formulas with many services (e.g. zabbix-formula) is straightforward, except that they use dedicated config file for each service.

`file.append` looks promising, but I still haven't realized how to do it. (E.g. `service1` uses `file.managed` and `service2` uses `file.append`; but when `service1` again runs - it will remove content of `service2`)? `file.blockreplace` might do the job, but I prefer to avoid dealing with markers.

Any idea or examples how to make it happen easily?

Comment: Any of the options you have described would work.

Comment: Then I probably don't understand how to do it. I have some ideas with prepend / append - let me try

Comment: ah prepend / append is not good because it will just inflate config when some parameter changes

Comment: So don't say 'it would work' - either show an example where it works or show how to do it. There is no point in this forum if universal answer is 'it is possible to do it'.

Comment: file.keyvalue is also kind of bad, because it will need additional state for removed values, which is unnecessary complexity.

Comment: There is no point in this site (which is not a forum) if questions don't have single objective answers. You need to ask about a specific programming problem. There are multiple solutions to this question, and they all have different pros and cons depending on your opinions.

Comment: problem is very specific. take zabbix-formula and make all services use single config file. You will be surprised how non-trivial it is.

Comment: That's not specific at all. And is pretty questionable why you want to do that in the first place, when the established best way to do it is what it's already doing.

Comment: Because services that I need to salt use the same config. Did you spend any time to think about the problem or just arrogantly pretend that there is easy solution?

Comment: I'm not pretending there is an easy solution,. I am confirming that there are multiple solutions and none is clearly better. You need to ask a specific question about a specific solution you have tried, that is not based on opinion.

Comment: So many solutions that the question is too broad and opinion-based for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes. Because this site is not for sharing ideas. It's for answering specific programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

First let's assume, it's most important to you, that the intended use is to include specific formula states, per you example:

```yaml
include:
  - myservice.service1
  - myservice.service2
```

None of these `serviceX.sls` should actually create your config file with `file.managed`. If each service state would use `file.managed` itself, it would indeed replace changes made by other service states. Instead, use an include in each of these `serviceX.sls`, and use the `require` requisite.

## Plain approach

```
.
└── myservice
    ├── conf.sls
    ├── service1.sls
    └── service2.sls
```

`myservice/conf.sls`

```yaml
conf_present:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/myservice/conf
    - source: salt://<path>/conf.org
```

`myservice/service1.sls`

```yaml
include:
- .conf

set_service1:
  file.append:
    - name: /etc/myservice/conf
    - text: myvar2=B
    - require:
      - file: conf_present
```

etc.

This approach does have disadvantages:

- it's not really idempotent. `myservice.conf` always creates the default file, and drops any changes made to it. Then `myservice.serviceX` will modify the default file. Repeated runs of `myservice.service1` will always result in two changed states - since the default file is setup again.
- The use has to make sure, if multiple services are configured, to always include those states in union.

The advantage of this approach is it's low complexity. Compared to the saltstack template formula, this section's example is easy to understand.

## formula all the way

Since you are mentioning the zabbix-formula, I can assume you are using the current structure of the [template formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/template-formula). There is a `map.jinja` which allows to specify multiple information sources to filter information. Grains are only one option.

I'd suggest to create a defaults dictionary which includes such a particle:

```yaml
...
  config:
    services: []
```

The `config.services` list is by default empty. The user has to specify the information, e.g. by grain, or yaml files which services are to be used by a minion. Have a look into the [`map.jinja` documentation](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/template-formula/blob/master/docs/map.jinja.rst).

Having this structured information I'd use `file.accumulated` to compile the config file. For an extended description, have a look into this [blogpost](https://regilero.github.io/english/saltstack/2014/01/27/saltstack_use_file_accumulated_accumulators_with_file_managed_and_file_blockreplace/)

Now let's assume a minion is supposed to setup the conf for service1, and service2. The `map.jinja` will filter out the respective information and compiles this dictionary:

```yaml
...
  config:
    services:
      - service1
      - service2
```

With this information the config can be compiled idempotent. You let the user decide thanks to the formula's `map.jinja` (from the template formula) how to specify this information.

The states could have the following structure:

```
.
└── myservice
    ├── files
    │   └── conf.jinja
    ├── map.jinja
    ├── ...
    └── service.sls
```

`conf.jinja`

```yaml
myvar1=A

{%- if accumulator|default(False) %}
  {%- if 'myservices_acc' in accumulator %}
    {%- for line in accumulator['myservices_acc'] %}
{{ line }}
    {%- endfor %}
  {%- endif %}
{%- endif %}
```

`myservice.service`

```yaml
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# vim: ft=sls

{#- Get the `tplroot` from `tpldir` #}
{%- set tplroot = tpldir.split('/')[0] %}
{%- from tplroot ~ "/map.jinja" import mapdata as myservice with context %}

services_config_present:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/myservice/conf
    - source: salt://{{ tpldir }}/myservice/files/conf.jinja
    - template: jinja

{%- if 'service1' in mapdata.config.services %}
service1_settings_added:
  file.accumulated:
    - name: myservices_acc
    - filename: /etc/myservice/conf
    - text: myvar2=B
    - require_in:
      - file: services_config_present
{%- endif %}

{%- if 'service2' in mapdata.config.services %}
service2_settings_added:
  file.accumulated:
    - name: myservices_acc
    - filename: /etc/myservice/conf
    - text: myvar3=C
    - require_in:
      - file: services_config_present
{%- endif %}
```

Moreover, you could include the `file_switch` pattern to parameterize the config file source path. Again the best resource is for this is the [docs](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/template-formula/blob/master/docs/TOFS_pattern.rst) of the template formula

Comment: Thanks for putting your time into detailed reply. It helps me to finalize thoughts in my head for sure. I have concerns reg `file.append` : suppose I changed some value later - I guess it will inflate the config instead replacing old code. Am I correct? Also I was thinking about using settings pillar to define which services should start, but I am afraid it hides too much - I prefer explicit calls for `myservice.service1` and `myservice.service2` . With your answer I ended up using `file.keyvalues` with downside that I will need another state to remove values. I was hoping there is smt better

Comment: Ah, also with file.append it will be nightmare when service1 is applied again after service2 and then service2 again, inflating config over and over, so I don't see how it can work